# Find all neighbours of a certain primitive in a CGAL::Surface_mesh

Tags: c++, cgal, raytracing

I wrote a small raytracer (with CGAL::Surface_mesh Mesh) with tree acceleration in cgal. I would like to find all neighbours of a hit primitive.

```
Ray_intersection hit = tree.first_intersection(rays[y][x]);

if(hit)
{
    const Point& point =  boost::get<Point>(hit->first);
    const Primitive_id& primitive_id = boost::get<Primitive_id>(hit->second);
    //i need the neighbours of the hit primitive
}
```

How do I this? I found this documentation but it seems to work only for points not primitives:

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_searching/index.html

And it searches for its euclidan distance not for being connected together.

Is there something like:

```
std::vector<Primitive_id&> ids = getNeighoursOfPrimive(primitive_id);
```

Like I said I am using CGAL::Surface_mesh Mesh for my mesh and their is only one mesh in the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the range returned by [`vertices_around_face()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIterators.html#ga7746cb7b28520877375dfff6ec7bd32c) to get all vertices of a face, then for each vertex you can use the range returned by [`halfedges_around_target()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIterators.html#gad73c04db7b6ce124c7855652c5940641) to get one halfedge per face incident to that vertex (or you can do it by hand using a combinaison of next and opposite).

Comment: Really care for the primitive, or the neighboring faces? If you want the neighboring faces, and primitive is AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive, the primitive ID is a boost::graph_traits<Surface_mesh>::face_descriptor (i.e. Surface_mesh::Face_index) and you can use BGL-like functions like CGAL::faces_around_face:

face_descriptor fd = p_id;
for(face_descriptor neigh_fd : CGAL::faces_around_face(halfedge(fd, sm), sm) // sm is your surface mesh
{

}

See the package BGL (it requires a data structure to fit an interface, which CGAL::Surface_mesh does using the 'graph_traits' interface).